# ng-style or style attribute with binding? Which is better? Which is faster? What is the difference?

Tags: angularjs

I am optimizing my large application. I am confused between following two approach, please help to decide which one is faster.

**Inline style attributes**

```
<div style="background-color:{{item.color}}"></div>
```

**Using ng-style**

```
<div ng-style="{'background-color':item.color}"></div>
```

**Using once-style**

```
<div once-style="{'background-color':item.color}"></div>
```

**Note** : For `once-style`, I have used AngularOnce Directive.

Thanks in advance. Please tell me which one is faster and why.

Comment: Good question. Always wondered why I would use ngStyle at all. Between ngStyle and onceStyle, speed wise it would be onceStyle because it doesn't set up a watcher, but that also means you can't dynamically change the color after it's set.

Comment: If you're optimising, then you must be benchmarking. If you're benchmarking, then you have everything set up to find out which of these is faster for yourself. Feel free to put your results in an answer to your own question.

Comment: @slim harsh but true...

Comment: Sure @slim, Well any other things which should I use to optimize my application as Its taking too load time and sometimes it crash. Angular looks painful at this moment.

Comment: BTW, using inline styles are not good at all for perfomance-wise. You should try to avoid them altogether if necessary (e.g. using a class + some CSS rule).

Comment: @ExpertSystem Yes, but my style is dynamic that depend on scope varibale so I have to use. If there is anything to do the same without inline style then feel free to suggest.

Comment: @JayShukla: If the color is totally dynamic (and not bound to a limited set of predefined values) then there is indeed not much you can do. Although, if the scope variable changes dynamically, I wonder how `once-style` is of any use to you here.

Comment: `<div style="background-color:{{item.color}}"></div>` String interpolation does not work In IE11 for style attribute. But `<div ng-style="::{'background-color':item.color}"></div>` will work for IE11

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you are optimizing your considerably large application, performance is definitely under question and I think `ngStyle` performs better as it sets up watch on the model and will update the view only if the model has changed.

So I would go with `ngStyle` or `onceStyle` depending on your scenario:

```
<div once-style="{'background-color':item.color}"></div>
```

Using `{{}}` will make Angular update the binding every digest cycle, even if the value has not changed.

Comment: Thanks. But would it be faster then style with interpolation as watch doesn't make any difference in my case as I am using ng-if so it will remove from and DOM and again will render on the basis of another flag.

Answer (score 33):

One time bind is available after Angular 1.3.

You can do this way without depending on third-party libraries:

```
<div ng-style="::{'background-color': item.color}"></div>
```

I didn't measure the performance, but I'm pretty sure that its better than without the colons.

Comment: What is the point of "::" before the expression ? @leonardoborges

Comment: @Dimitry it does a one time bind. The expression run only once, even if a new digest cycle occur.

Comment: @leonardoborges Thanks, wasn't able to find the docs for it... hard to search for "::" :)