# Process UI Change on callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some divs positioned as follows:

```
<div style="top: {{ item.top }}px;"></div>
```

In my controller, I have an array of elements:
    $scope.things = [{ "top": 10}];

I have JavaScript function in my controller that gets fired somewhat rapidly:

```
MyFunction.thingThatRunsCallbackRapidly(function(newTopValue) {
  $scope.things[0].top = newTopValue;
});
```

The top value of the things updates properly, but the element won't actually change its position until some other binding in my controller changes. What gives?

Comment: have you called `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: I have a feeling that you use ng-repeat without index by somewhere in your template. You should update the question with the template you use and with additional information about what you change in controller and what you expect from the template behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ng-style` instead of `style` if you want to dynamically update the value.

```
ng-style="{'top': item.top + 'px'}"
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: Does this have any additional benefit? Any reason to use this over evals in the style tag? Performance benefits, perhaps?

Comment: There are other cases where `ng-x` must be used for dynamically assigned attributes, but after some googling `style` doesn't seem like one of them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403107/ng-style-or-style-attribute-with-binding-which-is-better-which-is-faster-what