# AngularJS Directive once-style vs HTML global style attribute

Tags: html, angularjs

Why would I use one over the other, except if I need to define the style from a function?

```
<div once-style="{width:50%;}"/>
```

[once-style](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once)

```
<div style="width:50%;"/>
```

[HTML Style Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_style.asp)

If i have a fixed style in an AngularJS application is there a reason to use one over the other?

I tried finding relevant information, i just [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403107/ng-style-or-style-attribute-with-binding-which-is-better-which-is-faster-what) which really didn't answer my question.

Comment: Could you explain the downvote? And u deleted your comment

Comment: The comment wasn't mine. The downvote was, but it happened basically simultaneously with your edit. I think the question could still be more clear, but the edit improved it quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One time binding is native to Angular. Inside the curly braces prefix the expression with a double colon. For example:

```
{{::name}}
```

Comment: That is not what i asked, i understand the purpose of Angulars once directive and i know how to set it up. I am asking why i would use one over another. If its a binding once to the style attribute as i am asking about  int this case. Why wouldn't I just use htmls style="" attribute? is one faster than the other? Is its only purpose to allow a function to be called withing it? And the example usage is,  once-style="{color:blue}"

Comment: I see no reason to introduce a 3rd party thing for something that's native to HTML. Once is going to call code, the other isn't and there doesn't seem to be any benefit to it.

Comment: I agree, i couldn't find the purpose for it in my situation.

Comment: Yeah, IIRC, the one-way binding syntax was introduced in 1.3. I think this directive predates that. It may do some additional things, but seems to more or less be obsolete.

Comment: So is there a reason why one would need to "bind-once" anything other than data to html attributes? I mean even for classes and style tags ect.. If its not a function call and its not dynamic why would you use anything other than the native way?

Comment: I could see defining something dynamically in the constructor of a controller and binding to that, but I don't really have a particular use case in mind.